# How to convert string to decimal[] in C#

Tags: c#, string, decimal, converters

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried:

```
string str = "{34.10,0,0.00}"; //the string as I get it from Postgres DB
decimal[] won;

won = (decimal[])(str); //Cannot convert type 'string' to 'decimal[]'
```

What I would ideally want is to get into `won`:

```
won[0] = 34.10
won[1] = 0
won[2] = 0.00
```

Surely, I can go and split by commas, and put it in the array but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Any how you need to split.How would you do without splitting ?

Comment: @restless regex for example. still hardly what OP expects however

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to `Split`

```
won = str.Trim('{', '}').Split(',').Select(decimal.Parse).ToArray();
```

---

Edit: This part is just for fun

There is no way to cast string to a `decimal[]` array directly, but if you want you can add a decimal wrapper class and define implicit conversions:

```
class MyDecimal
{
    private decimal[] _values;

    public MyDecimal(int size)
    {
        _values = new decimal[size];
    }

    public decimal this[int index]
    {
        get { return _values[index]; }
        set { _values[index] = value; }
    }

    public static implicit operator MyDecimal(string str)
    {
        var numbers = str.Trim('{', '}').Split(',');
        MyDecimal d = new MyDecimal(numbers.Length);
        d._values = numbers
                    .Select(x => decimal.Parse(x,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();

        return d;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyDecimal md)
    {
        return string.Join(",", md._values);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
string str = "{34.10,0,0.00}"; //the string as I get it from Postgres DB
MyDecimal won = str;
```

Comment: What about the brackets?

Comment: "Surely, I can go and split by commas, and put it in the array but I'm wondering if there's a better way."

Comment: @Ksv3n yes and I'm using (Split(params char[]) )

Answer (score 1):

I first misread your question. The real answer is: I know of no other way than splitting and converting in loops or using LINQ (for a LINQ sample see Selman22's answer). There's no way to cast a string to an array in one go.

---

While it is essentially what you suggest, you could try this:

```
// Remove leading and trailing brackets
string s = str.Trim('{', '}');

// Split numbers
string[] parts = s.Split(',');
decimal[] nums = new decimal[parts.Length];

// Convert
for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
   nums[i] = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[i]);
```

Comment: "Surely, I can go and split by commas, and put it in the array but I'm wondering if there's a better way."

Comment: I know - that's why I changed my answer slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to play devil's advocate to those who say you have *no option* but to split:

```
var result = new JavaScriptSerializer()
    .Deserialize<decimal[]>(str.Replace('{', '[').Replace('}', ']'))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another but probably not a better way in regex

```
string str = "{34.10,0,0.00}";
string pattern = @"([\d]+[\.]|[\d]?)[\d]+";   
decimal[] result = Regex.Matches(str, pattern, RegexOptions.None)
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(x => decimal.Parse(x.Value))
                        .ToArray();
```

but remember Jamie Zawinski:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Another way would be using a StringReader and managing the split

Answer (score -3):

There is no better way. At least until C# is backed up by an AI which will just guess what you are trying to do by casting one datatype into another by a custom logic.

Any programmer would guess what you want. Until now though the C# compiler is no wizard.

Comment: It's not very polite, and there *is* a middle ground between manual parsing and inventing an AI.

Comment: @Rawling who said anything about inventing an AI to solve the problem? I said an AI would be required to solve what he is trying to do by simply attempting to convert datatype+data into what he wants, which is correct as well. Downvote is for incorrect answers or answers which don't answer the question, not for questions where you don't like the tone of.

Comment: also i just love how answers get accepted/upvoted which ignore OP's remark that he is wondering about ways without using Split. Ignore question content-answer randomly -> get upvotes.